# how to implement array for sybase tsql?

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

how to implement array function for tsql for sybase?
For example, I have 2 groups of data like:

```
g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6
a1,ab2,abc3,x4,y5,zzz6
```

I try to use varchar like:

```
declare @s1 varchar(1024) 
declare @s2 varchar(1024) 
set @s1 = 'g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6'
set @s2 = 'a1,ab2,abc3,x4,y5,zzz6'
```

then when I'm working on item g3, in first group, it's pos say it's 3. then I want to find out the matched one in @s2: 'abc3'

I try to use string function, but feel not efficency.

Not sure if sybase ase 12.5 support array. How to implement it with t-sql?

Answer (score 2):

Sybase unfortunately doesn't support array type. I recommend you to use temporary table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays functionality can be achieved through either using cursors or csv format with charindex function within while loop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).